# How to use animatorSet to change background color of a View

Tags: android, android-animation, animator

I am aiming at animating different things simultaneously.
I have successfully used AnimatorSet to scale up my textView

```
val textViewAnimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txtView, View.SCALE_X, 0.8f, 1.2f)
val textViewAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txtView, View.SCALE_Y, 0.8f, 1.2f)

val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
animatorSet.playTogether(textViewAnimatorX, textViewAnimatorY)
animatorSet.setDuration(500)
animatorSet.start()
```

How can i use animator set to simultaneously change the root view background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume this is your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is text view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code to simultaneously change the root view background color.

```
val textViewAnimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txtView, View.SCALE_X, 0.8f, 1.2f)
val textViewAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txtView, View.SCALE_Y, 0.8f, 1.2f)

// Create a new ObjectAnimator instance to change background color of root view.
val currentColor = rootView.solidColor
val newColor = Color.GREEN
val rootViewBackground = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
    rootView,
    "backgroundColor",
    ArgbEvaluator(),
    currentColor,
    newColor
)

val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
// Simultaneously change the root view background color.
animatorSet.playTogether(textViewAnimatorX, textViewAnimatorY, rootViewBackground)
animatorSet.setDuration(500)
animatorSet.start()
```

Comment: thanks for answer. How do i reset a view to default after doing this?

Answer (score 1):

creat `ObjectAnimator` instance to change color

```
val backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view,"backgroundColor",
                                                                       ArgbEvaluator(),
                                                                       0xFFFFFFFF,//color you like
                                                                       0xff78c5f9)
val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
animatorSet.playTogether(textViewAnimatorX, textViewAnimatorY,backgroundColorAnimator)// add your backgroundColorAnimator here
animatorSet.setDuration(500)
animatorSet.start()
```